# Why are the selected user's not receiving their messages?

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to allow user's to send messages to each other. As of right now I have the layout for the receiver and sender set up as well as my recycle view. When a user tries to message someone, the message get's sent and loads into recycle view successfully but the receiver does not receive that message, however it does appear for the sender. The way I basically tried doing it is when the user selects someone to message, I store the selected user's  UID as the receiver and the sender will be the currently logged in user.

```
//Loads data into views
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        //logged in user will be the sender of the message
        String senderOfMessage = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Message  message= userMessagesList.get(i);

        String  receiverOfMessage = message.getReceiver();



        if(receiverOfMessage.equals(senderOfMessage)){
            viewHolder.senderTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.senderTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages_layout);
            viewHolder.senderTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewHolder.senderTextView.setText(message.getMessage());

        }else{
            viewHolder.receiverTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.receiverTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messages_layout);
            viewHolder.receiverTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewHolder.receiverTextView.setText(message.getMessage());


        }







    }
```

**This is how I'm Saving the messages**

```
   //saves messages to firebase
    public void saveMessages() {
        //store data under timestamp to prevent overriding current information from Firebase...
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss ");
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        messageTimeStamp = currentFirebaseUser.getUid() + formatter.format(date);

        String messageSender = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
        String messeaageReceiver = id;

        messageDictionary.put("message", messageInputEditText.getText().toString());
        messageDictionary.put("sender", currentFirebaseUser.getUid());
        messageDictionary.put("receiver", id);
        messesagesRef.child("Messages").child(messageSender).child(messeaageReceiver).push().setValue(messageDictionary);
        messageInputEditText.setText("");

    }
```

**This is how I retrieve it**

```
final String messageSender = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
        final String messeaageReceiver = id;
        //cleared message b4 to prevent duplication...
        messageList.clear();

        firebaseDatabase.child("Messages").child(messageSender).child(messeaageReceiver).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                messageList.add(messages);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Database structure **

```
qnrE4PTKbNdKNs33cKtx1qLEvnS2
 C0EBxNAEmahhTEztCIu1yNg4wQz1
 -LpBiC7SRcHuoxzPAxN8
 message:  "Hi"
 receiver: "C0EBxNAEmahhTEztCIu1yNg4wQz1"
 sender:   "qnrE4PTKbNdKNs33cKtx1qLEvnS2"
```

Comment: Hi perhaps rebuild the layout in a click handler/

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more Stark

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try implementing the method `getItemViewType` of Recycler view and define the layout type using your concept there.

`getItemViewType` returns an integer for view types so you can define a final integer

```
public static final int RECEIVER = 1;
public static final int SENDER = 2;
```

Now check the item view type using the concept

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    String senderOfMessage = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Message  message= userMessagesList.get(position);

    String  receiverOfMessage = message.getReceiver();

    if(receiverOfMessage.equals(senderOfMessage)) 
        return [SENDER OR RECEIVER according to your condition]
    else
        return [SENDER OR RECEIVER according to your condition]

    return -1;
}
```

Now use `getItemViewType(i)` as the first statement in your `onBindViewHolder` to show the respective layout.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    int itemViewType = getItemViewType(i);

    if(itemViewType == [RECEIVER or SENDER]){
        viewHolder.senderTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.senderTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages_layout);
        viewHolder.senderTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewHolder.senderTextView.setText(message.getMessage());

    } else{
        viewHolder.receiverTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.receiverTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messages_layout);
        viewHolder.receiverTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewHolder.receiverTextView.setText(message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by  return [SENDER OR RECEIVER according to checking]

Comment: It means returning SENDER or RECEIVER according to your condition. 
`receiverOfMessage.equals(senderOfMessage)`

Comment: Thats basically  what I did above, the problem is that the user I choose to send a message too is not receiving the messages..  Only the sender message is being displayed.